# Identify a block diagonal matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I need to check if a matrix is a diagonal block matrix or not. Is there any easy way to check it? Especially, that would be perfect if a simple function such as `isdiag()`exist.

Comment: are the sizes of the blocks the same?

Comment: @Ram: Please explain what a diagonal block matrix is. What sizes do the blocks have. Can they contain zeros?

Comment: They can be same or different depends on result. I need something that can handle with both case.

Comment: @Daniel in my study, block matrices do not have to be in same size. And, yes they can contain zeros. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix

Comment: @Ram: Trivial answer, every matrix is a diagonal block matrix because it has one block filling the full matrix. This block is placed on the diagonal.

Comment: @Daniel: Can you look at the example below given by Matt. The matrix B is not a diagonal matrix although it is a block diagonal matrix.

Comment: @Ram: Why? According to your explanation of a diagonal block matrix it is one.

Comment: I have found a good explanation of block diagonal matrix here; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5-yMhZxmuDM. Based on this tutorial, Matrix B is block diagonal matrix, because rest of the blocks is zero. However, it is not a diagonal matrix, because B(2,3)=3 is not zero.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86631/discussion-between-daniel-and-ram).

Answer (score 0):

A function **[`isdiag`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isdiag.html)** actually exists for R2014a and later. It works for square and non-square matrices. For earlier versions of Matlab see an alternative below.

*Here is a quick demo:*

```
A = [1 0 0;
     0 2 0;
     0 0 3];
isdiag(A)

B = [1 0 0;
     0 2 3;
     0 0 4];
isdiag(B)

C = [1 0 0 0;
     0 2 0 0;
     0 0 3 0];
isdiag(C)

D = [1 0 0 0;
     0 2 0 3;
     0 0 4 0];
isdiag(D)
```

*... and we get:*

```
ans =
     1
ans =
     0
ans =
     1
ans =
     0
```

---

In R2014a and later, you can as well use **[`isbanded`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isbanded.html)** with a lower and upper bandwidth of `0`. This will give you exactly the same result:

```
isbanded(M,0,0)
```

---

For versions **before R2014a**, you can use a combination of `find` and `all`:

```
[t1,t2] = find(M);
res = all(t1==t2)
```

Comment: @HamtaroWarrior: Thanks for the remark... I added a solution for R2014a and earlier.

Comment: isdiag works well to identify diagonal matrix. However, It might fail in case block diagonal matrix. For example, the result of isdiag for matrix D is 0 although it is a block diagonal matrix.

Comment: @Ram According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_diagonal_matrices), `D` is not a block diagonal matrix. If you have another definition, please add it in the question and I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Sorry I meant matrix B. First block is 1 (1x1 matrix), second block is 2,3,0,4 (2x2 matrix). And rest of the elements of matrix B is zero.

Comment: `isdiag` identifies diagonal matrices, not diagonal block matrices.

Comment: @Daniel You are correct and that's what I indended to test for according to the Wikipedia article linked above. After watching the Youtube video, I know what he means with diagonal block matrix. But testing for this is not so trivial and there are several possibilities of *forming* such a matrix.

Comment: At the wikipedia article, A and 0 are both blocks, not scalars.

Comment: @Daniel - You are right, I missed that every A_n is a square matrix itself. Just rhetorically, why checking then if it is a diagonal block matrix, when basically every matrix meets this criteria? Edit: I just saw the chat log, I agree and that's what I meant. The full matrix can be seen as a single block.